# How to set default profile picture based on gender in android

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

I have two images male and female. I want to set image male if my gender is contains male and set image female if my gender is contains female.

The string gender is getting from JSON array.

Here is my code.

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONArray jsonarray = null;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_ID= "id";
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE= "user";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_MOB = "phn_number";
    private static final String TAG_PER_ADD= "permanent_address";
    private static final String TAG_PRE_ADD = "present_address";
    private static final String TAG_OFF_ADD = "office_address";
    private static final String TAG_MRG_ANN = "anniversary";
    private static final String TAG_CITY = "city";
    private static final String TAG_DOB = "dob";
    private static final String TAG_NATIONALITY = "nationality";
    private static final String TAG_OCC = "occupation";
    private static final String TAG_MRG_STATUS = "martial_status";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_NOY = "no_of_years";
    private static String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    ListView list;
    TextView name, mobile, permanent_add, present_add, office_add,mrg_anni,city,date_of_birth,nationality,occupation,mrd_status,gender,no_of_yr,email;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> profile;
    ImageView male,female;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String url = "http://app.goholidays.info/user_login.php";
    String uid;
    View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_profile);
        profile = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        male = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimagemale);
        female = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimagefemale);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mob);
        permanent_add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.permanent_add);
        present_add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.present_add);
        office_add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.office_add);
        mrg_anni = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mrg_anni);
        city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city);
        date_of_birth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob);
        nationality = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nationality);
        occupation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.o);
        mrd_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mrd_status);
        gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
        no_of_yr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_of_years);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        new ReadJSON().execute();


    }
    private class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Profile.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Profile ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Profile.this);
            //String post_email = sp.getString("email", TAG_EMAIL);
            String post_id = sp.getString("id",uid);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", post_email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",post_id));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
            // Check your log cat for JSON response
            try {
                    jsonarray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE);
                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        uid = jsonobject.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = jsonobject.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String phn_number = jsonobject.getString(TAG_MOB);
                        String permanent_address = jsonobject.getString(TAG_PER_ADD);
                        String present_address = jsonobject.getString(TAG_PRE_ADD);
                        String office_address = jsonobject.getString(TAG_OFF_ADD);
                        String anniversary = jsonobject.getString(TAG_MRG_ANN);
                        String city = jsonobject.getString(TAG_CITY);
                        String dob = jsonobject.getString(TAG_DOB);
                        String nationality = jsonobject.getString(TAG_NATIONALITY);
                        String occupation = jsonobject.getString(TAG_OCC);
                        String martial_status = jsonobject.getString(TAG_MRG_STATUS);
                        final String gender = jsonobject.getString(TAG_GENDER);
                        String no_of_years = jsonobject.getString(TAG_NOY);
                        String email = jsonobject.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, uid);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, StringUtils.capitalize(name.toLowerCase().trim()));
                        contact.put(TAG_MOB, phn_number);
                        contact.put(TAG_PER_ADD, permanent_address);
                        contact.put(TAG_PRE_ADD, present_address);
                        contact.put(TAG_OFF_ADD, office_address);
                        contact.put(TAG_MRG_ANN, anniversary);
                        contact.put(TAG_CITY, city);
                        contact.put(TAG_DOB, dob);
                        contact.put(TAG_NATIONALITY, nationality);
                        contact.put(TAG_OCC, occupation);
                        contact.put(TAG_MRG_STATUS, StringUtils.capitalize(martial_status.toLowerCase().trim()));
                        contact.put(TAG_GENDER, StringUtils.capitalize(gender.toLowerCase().trim()));
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
                                {
                                    male.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    female.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }else{
                                    male.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    female.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        contact.put(TAG_NOY, no_of_years+" Years");
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        profile.add(contact);

                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Profile.this, profile,
                    R.layout.newpage, new String[] {TAG_NAME, TAG_MOB, TAG_PER_ADD, TAG_PRE_ADD, TAG_OFF_ADD, TAG_MRG_ANN, TAG_CITY, TAG_DOB, TAG_NATIONALITY, TAG_OCC, TAG_MRG_STATUS, TAG_GENDER, TAG_NOY, TAG_EMAIL},
                    new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.mob, R.id.permanent_add, R.id.present_add, R.id.office_add, R.id.mrg_anni, R.id.city, R.id.dob, R.id.nationality, R.id.o, R.id.mrd_status, R.id.gender, R.id.no_of_years, R.id.email });
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

            //SharedPreferences prefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            //editor.putString("id",uid);
            //editor.commit();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

and my xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_110sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_121sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/male"
            android:id="@+id/profileimagemale"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_110sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_121sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/female"
            android:id="@+id/profileimagefemale"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_110sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll11"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_110sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEX:"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gender"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.8"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/faculties"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:hint="000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>
    </LinearLayout>
.........continued...................................
```

I am getting error nullpointerexception here is my logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hotel.yasmeenshaikh.GoHolidays.Profile$ReadJSON$1.run(Profile.java:156)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:574)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me solve this issue.

line number 156 is male.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Which line is this **com.hotel.yasmeenshaikh.GoHolidays.Profile$ReadJSON$1.run(Profile.java:156)**

Comment: what is your profile.java 156 line

Comment: `findViewById` returned you null views. Please debug and check

Comment: Post your xml code too

Comment: Have you initialize your imageviews? Show your full java class file

Comment: yes at the i will initialize like this ImageView male,female;

Comment: have you checked the json for typo error ?

Comment: Where did you put the initialisation of those imageView? And where did you call the request?

Comment: Wait i will post my full code and xml file

Comment: see my updated code.And thank you for your response

Comment: @user6657179 Check my answer !!

Comment: the errors indicate the views are not initialised when you are trying to update them. please verify that the update actions are happening after the views have been setup.

Comment: also I would advise you to do your UI operations in onPostExecute instead once you've got all your data.

Comment: Remain error is same

Answer (score 0):

Call     `new ReadJSON().execute();` after all views are initialized. Because it is executed before your views initialization.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.my_profile);
 profile = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

 male = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimagemale);
 female = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimagefemale);

 name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
 mobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mob);
 permanent_add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.permanent_add);
 present_add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.present_add);
 office_add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.office_add);
 mrg_anni = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mrg_anni);
 city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city);
 date_of_birth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob);
 nationality = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nationality);
 occupation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.o);
 mrd_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mrd_status);
 gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
 no_of_yr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_of_years);
 email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

  new ReadJSON().execute(); // Call here

}
```

Comment: now same error is on line number 159 in else loop first line

Comment: May be u did some wrong. Update your question with my code if u did

Comment: Where is this code in java file? I can't see. Post your updated java class file @user6657179

Comment: if my gender is male then error is showing here male.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) else gender is female error is showing here male.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: did u check my answer properly ?

Comment: yes i will check and i will assign that line at bottom; see my updated code

Comment: Ok and also removed from here _profile = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 new ReadJSON().execute();_ @user6657179

Comment: hey Now error in DoInBackground wait i will post the logcat

Comment: Which is 167 line?

Comment: if i use this initialize this line as it is before  profile = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); then error is like above logcat and after removing it error like below logcat

Comment: @user6657179 U have commented this line _profile = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();_. so getting error. Just uncomment that. Check my answer proper. I have updated it

Comment: after doing uncomment error is like above logcat as it is my first error

Comment: @user6657179 Are you mad? Just check my answer properly and doing same way

Comment: dud i will just make copy paste u r answer.

Comment: first u says that remove that line after u says update u r code with my code i will also do that.. after doing all the stuff u r saying me mad..Thank Dud thanks for u r suggesion